# Dynamically create module-based components in a root-level modal service

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/global-modal-lazy-components to demonstrate the problem.

I have an Angular application which is broken down into modules. At the app.module level there is a modal component and service.

Each module contains its own set of components and some of these may need to be hosted in the modal. However when I try to display one of these components - such as the password reset component in the Admin module, an error is thrown in the console:

`No component factory found for PasswordResetComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

How do I make module-level components available for the modal without having to create an instance of the modal service per module?

Comment: is upgrading angular to a newer version acceptable for you? This error will be resolved automatically. othervise the solution is harder

Answer (score 0):

I would upgrade Angular to newer version in your case. It would resolve your problem, and also it brings a lot of improvements in framework.

if upgrading is not acceptable for you then
try adding providers to HomeModule

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers:[ModalService]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

as a result another instance of ModalService will be created, which will use `HomeModule`s injector and also its `ComponentFactoryResolver`.

or if you don't like that solution you can try to pass the factory in item itself

```
content: [
    {
     item: this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(IceCreamComponent)
    }
  ],
```

and make "factory" branch inside of your service

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR;

[StackBlitz app.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/global-modal-lazy-components-wodcry?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Fadmin%2Fadmin.component.ts)

---

### Detailed solution

I think you can choose a simpler approach:

#### modal.component.html

```html
<div *ngIf="hasContent$ | async" class="container" (keyup.esc)="dismiss(closeOnEscape)">
  <div class="backdrop" (click)="dismiss(overlayDismiss)"></div>
  
  <div class="modal" #modal [ngClass]="dialogClass" [attr.id]="[id, '-modal'].join('')">
    <header class="header"><!-- ... --></header>
    <div class="body" [ngStyle]="styleModal()">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="modalService.contentSubject | async"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### modal.service.ts

```js
export class ModalService {
  /* ... */

  contentSubject = new BehaviorSubject<TemplateRef<any>>(null);

  public close() {
    this.contentSubject.next(null);
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

#### modal.component.ts

```js
class ModalComponent {
  /* ... */
  get hasContent$() {
    return this.modalService.contentSubject.pipe(filter(Boolean));
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

By doing this, the modal's consumer will simply send a `TemplateRef`. That's all it has to do, and it will be fully responsible for creating the modal's content. This allows also you to keep the modules clean, since you won't have to include components in other modules.

Let's see how you'd invoke the modal:

#### home.component.html

```html
<!-- ... -->
<button (click)="displayIceCreamModal()">Ice Cream?</button>

<ng-template #iceCream>
  <!-- You can customize it as you wish, from here. -->
    <app-ice-cream></app-ice-cream>
</ng-template>
```

#### home.component.ts

```js
class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('iceCream', { read: TemplateRef, static: true })
  private iceCreamTpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {}

  displayIceCreamModal () {
    this.modalService.contentSubject.next(this.iceCreamTpl);
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

As you can see, you define the content in the modal's consumer(in this case - the `HomeComponent`) and all you have to do to invoke the modal is to make the `this.modalService.contentSubject` Subject emit a new `TemplateRef` and with the help of the **async pipe** in `ModalComponent`'s view, you can easily get that `TemplateRef` instance.